# Java EE Specify Role to a System Method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

So basically I got Method-A that runs on Systemside (has no user assigned). Method-A uses Method-B that only allows specific Roles: **@RolesAllowed**({RoleConstants.ADMINISTRATOR,...})
The problem was that Method-A is not allowed to use Method-B.
So I came up with the idea of just declaring a Role (**@DeclareRoles**) to my Method-A but still it will just not work.
 
Is there anything I havent thought of?

Answer (score 1):

You can say to `Method-A` to run as one allowed role. Below the oficial documentation for that:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bncbh/index.html